# Does Nodejs cache local variables?

Tags: java, node.js, multithreading

If anyone is familiar with Java, Java has `volatile` modifier, which doesn't allow JVM to create a local copy of variables. This concept is important in the context of a multi-threaded environment of Java. I know that Nodejs is a single thread environment. It queued up a resource blocked task and executes a CPU-waiting task. Since there is only one thread and no-lock or thread-waiting concept is present, there doesn't seem to be a necessity of creating multiple local copies of a variable. Is there any local variable cache in Nodejs? And, if there is what is its use?

Comment: *Is there any local variable cache in Nodejs?* - there's no such thing because there's no need for such thing, as you already determined. There can be shared variables in workers, https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html

Comment: Java does not have a `virtual` modifier. Perhaps you are referring to c++, or the java keyword `volatile`?

Comment: And btw, it's just "Java", not "JAVA". It's not an acronym.

Comment: @LonelyCpp .. right! thanks.